# How to prevent IP spoofing for Azure VMs?

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-vm, azure-security, azure-nsg

I have an Azure web app which talks to the Azure VMs via Azure Load balancer. The VMs have NSG rules setup. The VMs are also being used by other servers/web apps. How do I prevent someone impersonating the IP and trying to get access to the VMs? Or how do I add another layer of security other than whitelisting the client IPs in the NSG of the VMs?

Answer (score 0):

**To secure Azure VMs, please try the following workarounds:**

- Make use of [**Azure Bastion**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-overview?Wt.mc_id=modinfra-11348-socuff), to securely connect to virtual machines from Azure Portal over TLS. If you are using Azure Bastion there is no need to create public IP on the Azure VM.
- Try creating [**DDoS protection plan**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ddos-protection/manage-ddos-protection#create-a-ddos-protection-plan) and enable it to your virtual network. DDoS protection plan is a paid service that offers enhanced DDoS mitigation capabilities.
- Make use of [**Azure Firewall**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/overview) which filters IPs by denying traffic from known malicious IP addresses.

**Enable all the above options in your virtual network like below:**
[image]

**Otherwise**,

- Make use of [**JIT (just-in-time)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/just-in-time-access-overview?WT.mc_id=modinfra-11348-socuff) VM access that allows only legitimate users to access the VM when necessary by reducing the attack.
- Try using [**VPN gateways**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways?WT.mc_id=modinfra-11348-socuff) which send encrypted traffic between Azure virtual networks. Please note that each virtual network can have only one VPN gateway.

For more information, please **refer** below links:

[How to secure a Windows Server virtual machine in Azure (microsoft.com)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/securing-a-windows-server-vm-in-azure/ba-p/1939268).

[Best practices for defending Azure Virtual Machines - Microsoft Security Blog](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2020/10/07/best-practices-for-defending-azure-virtual-machines/).